# How to simplify this equation including exponentials?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, problem-solving

In an [NLP paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2014/file/feab05aa91085b7a8012516bc3533958-Paper.pdf) there is the following equation that needs to be solved for x (I renamed some variables): $$y \cdot \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}-k \cdot w \cdot \frac{c}{D} \cdot \frac{1}{1+e^{x}} = 0$$

In the paper at the bottom of page 3 they do some massive simplification in a single step which I do not understand:

$$
e^{2 x}-\left(\frac{y}{k \cdot w \cdot \frac{c}{D}}-1\right) e^x-\frac{y}{k \cdot w \cdot \frac{c}{D}}=0
$$

Comment: I'm going to guess they did two things: multiplied everything by $(1+e^{-x})(1+e^x)$ and then again by $e^x$ to convert the powers to all positive powers of $e$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's exactly what they did, although they could have saved themselves some effort (and avoided introducing an extraneous solution) by just multiplying the first term by $\frac{e^x}{e^x}$ and putting everything on a common denominator.